# CodeIgniter insert_batch: Field 'exp_user' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert an array as a row to an "expenses" table on my DB:

```
public function insert_expense($expenses){
    $this->db->insert_batch('expenses', $expenses); 
}
```

and I keep getting this error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1364
>   Field 'exp_user' doesn't have a default value
>   INSERT INTO `expenses` () VALUES (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()
>   Filename: models/Expenses_model.php
>   Line Number: 26

This is the structure of my table:

[image]

And this is an example of what I'm trying to insert:

```
array(12) {
    ["exp_user"] "1"
    ["exp_date"] "2016-10-18"
    ["exp_date_request"] "2016-10-18"
    ["exp_client"] "Potato"
    ["exp_provider"] "Miew"
    ["exp_amount"] "1"
    ["exp_currency"] "₪"
    ["exp_budget"] "budget2"
    ["exp_method"] "cc"
    ["exp_frequency"] "Monthly"
    ["exp_expenditure"] "asdasdas asdas dsa as"
    ["exp_charge_client"] NULL
}
```

Comment: can you show expenses array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the variable `$expenses` is the array you have in your example:

```
$expenses = array(
    "exp_user" => "1",
    "exp_date" => "2016-10-18",
    "exp_date_request" => "2016-10-18",
    "exp_client" => "Potato",
    "exp_provider" => "Miew",
    "exp_amount" => "1",
    "exp_currency" => "₪",
    "exp_budget" => "budget2",
    "exp_method" => "cc",
    "exp_frequency" => "Monthly",
    "exp_expenditure" => "asdasdas asdas dsa as",
    "exp_charge_client" => NULL
);
```

You can't use it in the `insert_batch` function (since the `insert_batch` function expects to get an array of arrays (of data) as the second parameter).

Basically the `insert_batch` function gives you the ability to insert multiple rows (without looping over the `insert` function). You can just use multidimensional array for that:

```
$expenses = array(
    array(
        "exp_user" => "1",
        "exp_date" => "2016-10-18",
        "exp_date_request" => "2016-10-18",
        "exp_client" => "Potato",
        "exp_provider" => "Miew",
        "exp_amount" => "1",
        "exp_currency" => "₪",
        "exp_budget" => "budget2",
        "exp_method" => "cc",
        "exp_frequency" => "Monthly",
        "exp_expenditure" => "asdasdas asdas dsa as",
        "exp_charge_client" => NULL
    ),
    array(
        "exp_user" => "1",
        "exp_date" => "2016-10-18",
        "exp_date_request" => "2016-10-18",
        "exp_client" => "Potato",
        "exp_provider" => "Miew",
        "exp_amount" => "1",
        "exp_currency" => "₪",
        "exp_budget" => "budget2",
        "exp_method" => "cc",
        "exp_frequency" => "Monthly",
        "exp_expenditure" => "asdasdas asdas dsa as",
        "exp_charge_client" => NULL
    ),
    array(
        "exp_user" => "1",
        "exp_date" => "2016-10-18",
        "exp_date_request" => "2016-10-18",
        "exp_client" => "Potato",
        "exp_provider" => "Miew",
        "exp_amount" => "1",
        "exp_currency" => "₪",
        "exp_budget" => "budget2",
        "exp_method" => "cc",
        "exp_frequency" => "Monthly",
        "exp_expenditure" => "asdasdas asdas dsa as",
        "exp_charge_client" => NULL
    )
);
```

And now it makes sense to use the `insert_batch`.

If you have only 1 record you want to insert you can use the `insert` function:

```
$this->db->insert('expenses', $expenses);
```

Or change the call to:

```
$this->db->insert_batch('expenses', array( $expenses ) );
```